# \par in the parameter text (as an argument delimiter) and \vbox{#1} in an \everypar macro

Tags: errors, tex-core

This is basically a question about TeX's error messages.

I am confused by a cryptic error message that TeX gives me when I try to do the above. I have tried to isolate it, but have come no further than the following:

```
\def\foo#1\par{\vbox{#1}}
\def\bar#1\par{\hbox{#1}}

\let\macro\foo
\macro A paragraph consisting of text.

\let\macro\bar
\macro A paragraph consisting of text.

\everypar={\macro}
A paragraph consisting of text.

\let\macro\foo
A paragraph consisting of text.

\bye
```

This is all accepted by TeX, except the last example, which gives the error message:

```
! Argument of \macro has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
<to be read again> 
               }
l.16
```

"l. 16" points to the line before the `\bye`, i.e. to the moment where TeX encounters two consecutive newlines (causing it to insert a `\par` token, I assume).

I am aware that `\everypar` is inserted *after* the horizontal list has begun, and that it is not a very wise and clean idea to gobble up the paragraph *after* it has begun (so "the rest of the paragraph" would be the better description) and to typeset it inside a vbox. But then

```
\indent\vbox{This is some text.}
```

is accepted. Of course, if you typeset a whole paragraph inside a vbox inside the paragraph, the whole paragraph is typset to `\hsize` and shifted to the right by `\parindent` as a whole, which looks awful. But that is not my point.

What I would like to understand is why it is apparently not possible to a) put a macro in `\everypar` which b) gobbles up the whole (or rather: rest of the) paragraph and c) puts it into a vbox, while all of these things are apparently possible in isolation? In particular, if we only change c) to an hbox instead of a vbox, the error message disappears. In other words: Why does TeX suddenly see an extra `}` when we use a vbox?

As I have just typed all of this, something is beginning to dawn on me: Is the problem due to the fact that inside a vbox, TeX starts a new horizontal list, inserting the contents of `\everypar` once more, triggering an endless recursion? In that case, it would have nothing to do with the \par as an argument delimiter but simply with the fact that within `\everypar`, one should not start a new paragraph. Indeed, if I say

```
\def\macro#1\par{\vbox{\noindent}#1}
```

(assuming `\macro` is still in `\everypar` as above), the same error happens when the next paragraph is typeset.

So now it seems to me I have understood where the error comes from, but what does the error message mean? Why does TeX see an extra `}`? And why does it exactly report it after it has gobbled up the argument to `\macro`? If I say

```
\everypar={\vbox{\noindent}}
A paragraph consisting of text.
```

I get the error message

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500].
<everypar> \vbox {\noindent 
                            }
[many similar lines left out]
...
l.17 A
       paragraph consisting of text.
```

which seems clear in the context of what I seem to have figured out above.

**Edited in response to egreg's excellent explanations:**

[As to the point that my code as given above indeed does NOT cause any error messages; it does so -- and illustrates the problem I had -- if you put two empty lines between the examples instead of one.]

Your tip of putting \everypar={} inside the vbox is great, because that is local to the vbox, right?

What I would still love to know, however, is why in some examples, TeX reports an exceeded "nest size", which I find understandable, and in others (where the reason is the same), that the argument to the macro in everypar has an extra }. I know that TeX's error messages are notoriously cryptic, but I would like to know if it might be possible to make some sense of them anyway.

I will have a try:

When, after \everypar has been set to {\macro}, TeX encounters the next paragraph, it executes and expands \macro, which gobbles up the paragraph (and discards the implicit \par at the end) and then opens a vbox in which it puts the paragraph. Because the paragraph text in the vbox starts a new paragraph, \everypar is executed again, calling \macro again, which again gobbles up the paragraph text, but encounters the closing } of the vbox before any \par token. Thus, it is the second call of \macro which triggers this error message.

Is that the whole story? I would actually have expected that a closing } in a vbox should cause an implicit \par.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get no error from the first code.

Answer (score 5):

I get no error with the first example, unless I add a blank line between `\let\macro\foo` and `A`:

```
\def\foo#1\par{\vbox{#1}}
\def\bar#1\par{\hbox{#1}}

\let\macro\foo
\macro A paragraph consisting of text.

\let\macro\bar
\macro A paragraph consisting of text.

\everypar={\macro}
A paragraph consisting of text.

\let\macro\foo

A paragraph consisting of text.

\bye
```

Why? The `\par` preceding `\let\macro\foo` has been gobbled by `\bar`, so no new paragraph is started, in your example.

Now, why the error? By the same reason! When `\foo` is executed (under the name of `\macro`), the `\par` preceding `\bye` is gobbled as part of the parameter text, so when `A` is rescanned in the `\vbox` a paragraph is started and `\foo` is expanded again, but a trailing `\par` is missing. Hitting return will start an infinite loop.

This doesn't happen with `\hbox` because `\everypar` is not executed inside it.

“Solution”:

```
\def\foo#1\par{\vbox{\everypar{}#1}}
```

Of course, this will produce an overfull box, because of the indentation caused by the start of the paragraph and the fact that the `\vbox` will be `\hsize` wide.

---

You can't “solve” the issue by adding `\par` to the definition of `\foo`:

```
\def\foo#1\par{\vbox{#1\par}}
```

because this will cause

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500].
<to be read again> 
                   A
<argument> A
```

The reason is again that `A` will trigger a new paragraph, so a call of `\foo` and hence the opening of a `\vbox` where the `A` will be read again, triggering a new paragraph, so a call of `\foo`…

In this case, the program stops when 500 levels of boxing are attempted. The same problem explains the case you are getting the same error.

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed the code above is not 100% identical to the code I executed -- I stripped empty lines to make it less long. I did not notice this would make a difference, but now I completely get it.