# Using a macro with parameters in \everypar fails

Tags: tex-core

Out of curiosity, I wonder why this fails:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bla}{mm}{#1.#2!}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\obeylines
\everypar={\bla}
{C}{G} skdjfs;ldjkf;sjkf
{ERT}{ERTERT} djkfsjdfl;ksjdf;l
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

with the error: `Argument of \bla  has an extra }.` I did look at [\par in the parameter text (as an argument delimiter) and \vbox{#1} in an \everypar macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193551/par-in-the-parameter-text-as-an-argument-delimiter-and-vbox1-in-an-every) but these are not *delimited* arguments to a macro.

## Later...

I discovered that `xparse` offers a solution of sorts, though I think this might be looked upon as *abuse*:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bla}{O{}O{}}{#1.#2!}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\obeylines
\everypar={\bla}
[C][Gin] skdjfs;ldjkf;sjkf
[ERT][ERTERT] djkfsjdfl;ksjdf;l
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I assume that this works because the pesky `{` is no longer in play. This is convenient in that I can avoid putting `\bla` in front of each and every line (dozens of them).

Comment: Is there a reason you want `\obeylines` here? It makes the explanation longer ... though fundamentally the same

Comment: No. It was part of an earlier experiment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX is in vertical mode when it reads your `{C}` start-of-paragraph text. The `{` starts a group but does *not* change mode. That happens when TeX reads `C`, which must be in horizontal mode and so starts a paragraph. The `\everypar` tokens are inserted, and your macro grabs `C` as `#1` (you can see this if you use a macro with only one argument). In the current case, you then have a `}` in the input stream. That can't be `#2`, so you get a TeX error.

Probably the easiest way to avoid this is to force TeX to leave vertical mode. The standard `\leavevmode` won't work as it inserts some tokens that come *after* `\everypar`. We can fix that with an e-TeX definition for `\leavevmode`

```
\protected\def\leavevmode{\ifvmode\expandafter\indent\fi}
```

which can then be inserted

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bla}{mm}{#1.#2!}
\protected\def\leavevmode{\ifvmode\expandafter\indent\fi}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\everypar={\bla}
\leavevmode
{C}{G} skdjfs;ldjkf;sjkf
{ERT}{ERTERT} djkfsjdfl;ksjdf;l
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is e-tex specific here? The \protected naturally, but it seems to work also without it.

Comment: Somewhere in the TeXBook there is a warning about beginning a paragraph with `{` -- can't find it now, but that should have made me think... This was a nice lesson.

Comment: Actually, having TeXed the code, I find that does not work. The first line works correctly giving typeset `C.G!  skdjfs;ldjkf;sjkf` but the second line gives typeset `E.R!ERTERT djkfsjdfl;ksjdf;l`. The code works if `\leavevmode` is placed before each line.

Comment: @sgmoye I've dropped the `\obeylines` as it makes life more tricky: perhaps you haven't?

Comment: @JosephWright I had absently put a return after the fist line. That led me to the discovery that `\leavevmode` is required before *each* line, and the realization that there is no real labor-savings in using a macro with parameters inside `\everypar` It would be nice if there were...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You need the definition to be `\protected`, so this approach can only work with e-TeX. The problem comes at the start of an `\halign` cell: a mode test is not reliable there. Try for example `\begin{array}{c}\ifvmode T\else\ F\fi`, which is what you get with a non-`\protected` macro. That's why without e-TeX you need the DEK definition of `\leavevmode`. Perhaps this is one for a separate question. (The e-TeX version is 'better' as it leaves no tokens in the input stream.)

Comment: Ah. ok. So you don't need it here but in general for \leavevmode to work.